# UIDocumentInteractionController ios5 how to add Mail app

Tags: ios, ios5, uidocumentinteraction

I'm displaying a png with an UIDocumentInteractionController.
Is it possible to add Mail App to the available apps? With a fresh firmware installation there's only the printer, while on iOS 6 there are many default options

thank you